# Create arrays from a multidimensional array by each index object value

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is an example of my main array:

```
[
  {
    'data': [{'value': 'Red'}, {'value': 'Small'}, {'value': 'Good'}]
  },
  {
    'data': [{'value': 'Black'}, {'value': 'Medium'}, {'value': 'Bad'}]
  },
  {
    'data': [{'value': 'White'}, {'value': 'Large'}, {'value': 'Best'}]
  }
]
```

And I want as output:

```
[
  ['Red', 'Black', 'White'],    // all values from first index of data array
  ['Small', 'Medium', 'Large'], // all values from second index of data array
  ['Good', 'Bad', 'Best']       // all values from third index of data array
]
```

I have tried with `forEach` , `for...in`, `filter` etc. But I did not success to get the previous output.

Comment: Hi!! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for comment. next time i will share my code. already I get my answer. so next time of course i will  share my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` and then within the reduce loop use `forEach()`. In the `forEach` loop use the index to determine which array to push. It there's no value yet at that index, make a new array and push into that:

```js
let data = [{'data': [{'value': 'Red'},{'value': 'Small'},{'value': 'Good'}]},{'data': [{'value': 'Black'},{'value': 'Medium'},{'value': 'Bad'}]},{'data': [{'value': 'White'},{'value': 'Large'},{'value': 'Best'}]}]

let arr = data.reduce((arr, item) => {            // look at each item in the data array
  item.data.forEach(({value}, index) => {         // look at each item in the item.data array
    (arr[index] || (arr[index] = [])).push(value) // create and array if necessary and push value into it
  })
  return arr
},[])

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: I like this one, reduce would be my first option too, +1

Answer (score 1):

You can also try as the below example shows.

> **filter()** method is basically  used when we want filtered output based on some conditions.

```
var a = [
    {
       'data': [
       {
          'value': 'Red'
       },
       {
        'value': 'Small'
       },
      {
        'value': 'Good'
       }
     ]
    },
    {
        'data': [
        {
        'value': 'Black'
        },
        {
        'value': 'Medium'
        },
       {
        'value': 'Bad'
       }
     ]
   },
     {
     'data': [
      {
        'value': 'White'
      },
      {
        'value': 'Large'
      },
      {
        'value': 'Best'
      }
      ]
     }
    ]


var obj = {};

for(var o of a) {
    for(var i in o.data) {
        if(obj[i] === undefined) {
            obj[i] = [o.data[i].value];
        } else {
            obj[i].push(o.data[i].value);
        }
    }
}

console. log(obj);
/*
{ '0': [ 'Red', 'Black', 'White' ],
  '1': [ 'Small', 'Medium', 'Large' ],
  '2': [ 'Good', 'Bad', 'Best' ] }
*/
```

Comment: Hi @hygull, the result is displaying multiple times

Comment: It's not the desired result (`['Red', 'Black', 'White']` ... etc)

Comment: Now I have updated my answer. Thank you for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution to your problem, using a main loop over the number of different properties you want to read, and inside each loop uses the facility provides by the method [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
let a = [
    {'data': [{'value': 'Red'}, {'value': 'Small'}, {'value': 'Good'}]},
    {'data': [{'value': 'Black'}, {'value': 'Medium'}, {'value': 'Bad'}]},
    {'data': [{'value': 'White'}, {'value': 'Large'}, {'value': 'Best'}]}
];

// The new array.
let newArr = [];

// Number of properties for each "data" object.
let keys = 3;

for (let k = 0; k < keys; k++)
{
    newArr.push(Array.from(a, v =>  v.data[k].value));
}

console.log(newArr);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Alternatively, you can replace `Array.from()` by [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), like this:

```
for (let k = 0; k < keys; k++)
{
    newArr.push(a.map(v => v.data[k].value));
}
```

**Example:**

```js
let a = [
    {'data': [{'value': 'Red'}, {'value': 'Small'}, {'value': 'Good'}]},
    {'data': [{'value': 'Black'}, {'value': 'Medium'}, {'value': 'Bad'}]},
    {'data': [{'value': 'White'}, {'value': 'Large'}, {'value': 'Best'}]}
];

// The new array.
let newArr = [];

// Number of properties for each "data" object.
let keys = 3;

for (let k = 0; k < keys; k++)
{
    newArr.push(a.map(v =>  v.data[k].value));
}

console.log(newArr);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```